# Sum all numbers in a range

Tags: javascript, programming-challenge, array

I have implemented the "Sum All Numbers in a Range" challenge from [Free Code Camp](http://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/sum-all-numbers-in-a-range) quoted below.

The code works like a charm, but I don't think it's idiomatic. The challenge hints imply I should be using `Math.max()`, `Math.min()` and `Array.reduce()`. In addition I used the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) from ES6 to simplify both `Math` calls.

I'm looking for a more idiomatic way to solve this. I think it can be done in a one-liner, something like:

```
return arr.sort((function(a, b) { return a - b; })).reduce(function(a, b) { /* */ });
```

But I'm pretty sure I'm heading the wrong way with the above.

The challenge:

> We'll pass you an array of two numbers. Return the sum of those two numbers and all numbers between them.
>
> The lowest number will not always come first.

The code:

```
function sumAll(arr) {
  var out = 0;
  for (var i = Math.min(...arr); i <= Math.max(...arr); i++) {
    out += i;
  }
  return out;
}
```

Test cases:

```
sumAll([1, 4])
sumAll([4, 1])
sumAll([5, 10])
sumAll([10, 5])
```

Expected output:

```
10
10
45
45
```

Comment: How do you get freecodecamp to use es6?

Comment: @Barry It's not allowed for every challenge for some reason, but on this one it just gave a notification ES6 was required. Nothing else.

Comment: ever heard of Gauss? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Friedrich_Gauss#Anecdotes)

Comment: the oneliner you give is very close. in the final function you have a and b being the min and max values. just apply gauss to it: `return (a+b)*(b-a+1)/2;`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't know what you would use `reduce()` for to be honest. But you don't need to loop. We just have a simple arithmetic sequence with a straightforward formula:

$$\sum_{i=min}^{max} i = \frac{(max-min+1)(min+max)}2$$

We just need to pick out which one is larger:

```
function sumFrom(min, max) {
    return (max-min+1) * (min+max) / 2;
}

function sumAll(arr) {
    return sumFrom(Math.min(...arr), Math.max(...arr));
}
```

Or we could generalize to any arithmetic sequence:

```
function sumArithmetic(a1, n, d) {
    return n*(2*a1 + (n-1)*d) / 2;
}

function sumAll(arr) {
    var min = Math.min(...arr);
    return sumArithmetic(min, Math.max(...arr) - min + 1, 1);
}
```

---

I guess if you really want `reduce()` you'd do it this way (not using ES6 because I don't know how to get freecodecamp to use it):

```
function sumAll(arr) {
  var min = Math.min.apply(null, arr);
  var max = Math.max.apply(null, arr);

  return Array.apply(null, Array(max-min+1))   // get array of correct size
      .map(function(_, b) { return b+min; })   // change it to have correct values
      .reduce(function(a, b) { return a+b; }); // and sum it
}
```

Comment: you would use reduce because it is a way to not access the array by indexes.

Comment: $max(a,b)-min(a,b)=|a-b|$, $min+max=a+b$ saves you some steps.

Answer (score 4):

Like Barry mentioned, you are probably expected to use Gauss and the property of triangular numbers.

`reduce` is a funny way of accessing your array without touching the indexes, hence without needing to verify that they exist. (consider what would happen if your function was called with `[]` or `[0]`).

The one-liner you give is very close. In the final function you have `a` and `b` being the `min` and `max` values in that order. just apply the sum formula to it: `return (a+b)*(b-a+1)/2;`

So:

```
return arr
        .sort((a, b) => a - b)
        .reduce((a, b) => (a + b) * (b - a + 1) / 2);
```

You'll notice that since the array is size 2 and known to be that way, the complexity is `O(1)`, while if you actually sum the numbers, it becomes `O(n)` where n is the amount of numbers to add.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I'd change `out` to `result`. And also the structure in something like the following:

```
function sumAll(arr){
    var smallest = 0;
    var greatest = 0;

    if(arr[0] < arr[1]){
        smallest = arr[0];
        greatest = arr[1];
    } else{
        smallest = arr[1];
        greatest = arr[0];
    }

    return sumRange(smallest, greatest);
}

function sumRange(from, to){
    var result = 0;

    for(var i = from; i <= to; i++){
        result += i;
    }

    return result;
}
```

In this way it becomes more readable IMO.

Comment: Javascript does not support ad hoc polymorphism. only the second function exists.

Comment: @njzk2 thanks for pointing that out. Silly mistake. Now it should be ok.